# Issue with Microsoft Bot Composer publishing in Microsoft Azure

Tags: c#, .net, azure, botframework, azure-bot-service

I'm currently facing an issue with Microsoft Bot Composer when attempting to publish it in Microsoft Azure. I have followed all the steps outlined in the official documentation, but unfortunately, I'm still encountering difficulties.

1.I carefully reviewed the official documentation for publishing a bot from Microsoft Bot Composer to Microsoft Azure.
2.I followed the step-by-step instructions provided in the documentation, ensuring that I didn't miss any crucial details.
3.I verified that I have all the necessary prerequisites and configurations in place before attempting the deployment.
4.I attempted the publishing process multiple times, but each time I encountered the same problem.

Error Messages

```
Provision partially completed
Provisioning completed 1 items before encountering a problem. {"name":"CREATE_WEB_APP_ERROR","message":"Error - {\"Code\":\"429\",\"Message\":\"App Service Plan Create operation is throttled for subscription
```

Please let me know if there are any additional details or troubleshooting steps I can provide to help diagnose the issue

I expected to be able to successfully publish my bot from Microsoft Bot Composer to Microsoft Azure without any issues.

Comment: Check this Doc if helps https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/machine-learning/how-to-troubleshoot-online-endpoints.md

Answer (score 0):

“Too Many Requests” when attempting to publish your bot from Microsoft Bot Composer to Microsoft Azure. This error can occur when the rate limit for a particular resource has been exceeded.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/composer/faq/composer-faq